# Calling a url from one app to another in Django

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-apps

How do you access a namespaced url from a template of an app where the namespaced url is located in another app?  I tried

```
"{% url 'mynamespace:url' %}"
```

But I get NoReverseMatch and  mynamespace is not a registered namespace error but I have, `app_name = 'mynamespace'` in the concerned app.

here is the urls of the app that is accessed from another app.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = "mynamespace"
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.myview, name='myview'),
]
```

Comment: Make sure you have added your app in the `INSTALLED_APPS` of `settings.py`.

Comment: all apps are added.

Comment: Please show the contents of the app's `urls.py`.

Comment: Can you show your root `urls.py` as well? @flowfree `INSTALLED_APPS` has no effect on urls.